# Nexus: Unable to get artifact from a proxy repository

Tags: maven, nexus

I installed Nexus and I proxied some external repositories.

Now I'm trying to proxy `http://repo.opengeo.org/` but when I add a dependency through m2eclipse, it finds no result.

If I try to browse the Repository index via web interface, I get nothing; same story if a search the artifact via web GUI.

However, if I browse the remote repo everything is displayed correctly.
Is there something else to do?

It seems that, when you add a new repository, the behaviour is totally unpredictable. It is driving me crazy...

Comment: If the remote repository is a fully fledged Maven repository then it will contain a lucene index that your Nexus repository manager can be configured to download. If such an index doesn't exist then only artifacts downloaded will appear in your local index. This might explain the difference between browsing the repo contents and browsing the repo index.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if there is a way to build the index for a proxy repo? thx in advance.

Comment: If the remote repository does not publish it's index, it's very difficult. You could retrieve all it's content (thereby updating your local index) but it's then a chicken and egg problem (index is normally used to find the repo contents)....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The remote repository isn't publishing an index, but that won't affect your ability to get artifacts from it. Just add the proxy, add it to your group, add the artifact to your pom and build.

Comment: ok thanks. It works. But this way I loose the opportunity to make a search with m2eclipse "Add Dependencies". It's not fundamental but it's quite useful.